# Javascript/JQuery if style display value is equal to

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I want to check if the display is equal to none or to table-row. I'm currently using this:

Javascript/JQuery:

```
function changeDisplay(element){
    var clickedLi = $(element).closest("li");
    var pageList = $(".paginering li");
    var trList = $(".tabelOpenstaand tbody tr.hoofdRij");
    var trNumber = $(".tabelOpenstaand tbody tr.hoofdRij").length;

    debugger;

    for (var i = 0; i < trNumber; i++){
        if (trList[i].css("display") == "table-row"){
            trList[i].css("display", "none");
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I get the error: 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' on the if line. How do I solve this? trList is filled with the right elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead trList[i], try trList.eq(i)

It would become

```
    if (trList.eq(i).css("display") == "table-row"){
        trList.eq(i).css("display", "none");
    }
```

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of answers with associated workarounds, but no one has really explained the reason why this is failing.

`$('selector')` returns a jQuery object. This object has numerical indices that hold DOM elements.

This means that `$('selector')[0]` returns a DOM element, not a jQuery object, and therefore does not have the `.css()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What would be the best solution with this in mind?

Comment: Personally, I think `.each(...)` is the idiomatic way of looping through jQuery objects.

Answer (score 0):

`trList` is not an array it's an object. So `trList[i]` won't work.

You will have to make a foreach.

```
trList.each(function(){
   if($(this).css("display") == "table-row"){
      $(this).css("display", "none");
   }
});
```

Comment: `trList[i]` is perfectly valid in this instance (even if it's an object), it just does not return a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

When i walk an object, i often write code like this :

```
function changeDisplay( element ){
    // var clickedLi = $(element).closest("li");
    // var pageList = $(".paginering li");
    // var trList = $(".tabelOpenstaand tbody tr.hoofdRij");
    // var trNumber = $(".tabelOpenstaand tbody tr.hoofdRij").length;

    var trList = document.querySelectorAll( ".tabelOpenstaand tbody tr.hoofdRij" );

    for ( var i in trList ){
        if( !i.match( /\D/ ) continue;
        if( trList[i].css("display") == "table-row" ){
            trList[i].css( "display", "none" );
        }
    }
}
```

The "String.match()" is usefull when i'm walking in an object. And I prefer use "for( var ... in ... )" syntax. Just personal point of view.